# How can I apply delogo for a duration of video in ffmpeg or apply delogo in mutiple areas?

Tags: ffmpeg

I just learned the way to delogo in ffmpeg:

```sh
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf delogo=x=1539:y=23:w=353:h=93 output.mp4
```

I would like to know if it is possible to apply delogo filter only for a clip?

And can I apply delogo to two squares?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use the `enable` option

The delogo filter supports the [`enable` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) (timeline support). You can see if a filter supports this option with `ffmpeg -filters`.

### Apply delogo filter between 5-10 seconds

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "delogo=x=1539:y=23:w=353:h=93:enable='between(t,5,10)'" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

### Apply delogo to multiple areas

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "delogo=x=1539:y=23:w=353:h=93,delogo=x=100:y=24:w=100:h=72" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

### Apply delogo to two squares between 5-10 seconds

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "delogo=x=1539:y=23:w=353:h=93:enable='between(t,5,10)',delogo=x=100:y=24:w=100:h=72:enable='between(t,5,10)'" -c:a copy output.mp4
```